# Search and replace value in columns in DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes pandas :

**IpAddress_to_Country_data**

```
lower_bound_ip_address  upper_bound_ip_address  country
1.677722e+07    16777471    Australia
1.677747e+07    16777727    China
1.677773e+07    16778239    China
1.677824e+07    16779263    Australia
1.677926e+07    16781311    China
```

and **fraud_data**:

```
ip_address  
7.327584e+08
3.503114e+08    
2.621474e+09    
3.840542e+09    
4.155831e+08
```

I need to search if ip_address is between lower_bound and upper_bound and replace ip_address by country.
I converted dataframe into np.array :

```
a = np.array(fraud_data.ip_address)
b = np.array([IpAddress_to_Country_data.lower_bound_ip_address, IpAddress_to_Country_data.upper_bound_ip_address, IpAddress_to_Country_data.country])
```

and I coded this to search each value, replace it and store in list c:

```
for j in range(0, len(a)):
    for i in range(0, b.shape[1]):
        if b.transpose()[i][0] < a[j] < b.transpose()[i][1]:
            c.append(b.transpose()[i][2])
```

My solution seems good but it takes a lot of time because I have 151112 rows.
I tried to make list comprehension or lambda function but I did not manage to run a good solution.

Do you have an idea to improve this solution ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: All IP addresses are higher than the upper bounds. Maybe share a better example, and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting your pandas dataframe to numpy arrays defeats the purpose of using dataframes in the first place!

You can use powerful pandas built-in tools to test if the values in **ip_address** are between **ip_address is between lower_bound** and **ip_address is between upper_bound**

I would suggest first concatenating your two dataframes:

```
df=pd.concat([IpAddress_to_Country_data, fraud_data.reindex(IpAddress_to_Country_data.index)], axis=1)
```

Then you can use `between` to determine whether values in the 'ip_address' column are comprised between those of the lower and upper bounds:

```
df['ip_address'].between(df['lower_bound_ip_address'],df['upper_bound_ip_address'])
```

Now, as pinpointed by yatu in his comment, this will return a colmun full of `False` values since all your IP addresses exceed the upper bounds!